# Integer string in xpath selenium not working

Tags: selenium

i am newbie in selenium. trying to loop through a dropdown list of premium selection. if i manually change the integer, it's working but however if i put in '" + str(i) + "' an error msg:
ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable. have been googling for hours for solutions :(
apologies if the codes are not properly placed. was also trying to figure that out. thanks for any help rendered

```
> i=3
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='contentBody']/div[4]/div[2]/ul/li/div/div[1]").click()
driver.implicitly_wait(1)
elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='contentBody']/div[4]/div[2]/ul/li/div/div[2]/div/div['" + str(i) + "']")
elem.click()
premium = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='contentBody']/div[4]/div[2]/ul/li/div/div[1]/div").text
print (premium)
driver.implicitly_wait(2)
```

Comment: Try: `driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='contentBody']/div[4]/div[2]/ul/li/div/div[2]/div/div[" + str(i) + "]")` don't need quote `(')` in `[]`

Comment: Thanks frianH! that works! had tried  ' + str(i) + ' but somehow not " + str(i) + "